# Open connection to DB2 database from CLR code in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, db2, sqlclr

I'm trying to connect to a DB2 database from a CLR method in our SQL Server database.
The connection is done over an OleDbConnection.
This worked before, but we're migrating to a new environment.
We used to work on an SQL Server 2014 using the IBM DB2 9.7 driver.
Now we're going to an SQL Server 2019 using the latest IBM DB2 11.5 driver.
Development is done in .NET Framework 4.8 and uses CLR 4.0. Because of the updated environment we now sign our CLR assembly with a certificate before publishing.

The CLR code itself works and can be called, but the OleDbConnection to the DB2 database doesn't work.
When running the `OleDbConnection.Open()` method we get the following error:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "clrGetData":
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException:
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

Strange thing is, when I make a simple console application which tries to connect to the same database over OleDb, using the same connection string and the same code for initializing the connection and such, the connection is opened without problems and calls can be done to the DB2 database.
I've tested this on both the application server (which calls the CLR method on our SQL Server database) and the database server (on which the CLR's run and make a connection to the DB2 database).

I also tried to connect to the DB2 database directly from our web application on the application server, by copying the CLR code to the web application. This also goes without any problems. However, as our current setups requires the sync between the 2 databases to be initialised from our database, it would be a lot or refactoring work to fully replace our CLR procedures.

This is an example of a CLR procedure we're testing at the moment:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void clrGetData(string userId)
{
    var connectionString = <Get connection string to DB2 database>;
    using (var db2connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        db2connection.Open();

        if (db2connection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("connection");

        Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData[] mdDos = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData[1];
        mdDos[0] = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData("Profile", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

        string storedProcedure = string.Format("<Name of SP on DB2 database>");

        var cmd = new DB2Command();

        cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = db2connection;

        // parameters
        OleDbParameter dbParam;
        dbParam = new OleDbParameter("<name>", OleDbType.Char, 10, "<srcColumn>");
        dbParam.Value = userId;
        dbParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(dbParam);

        // Some other input parameters
        // ...

        dbParam = new OleDbParameter("<name>", DB2Type.Integer, 10, "<srcColumn>");
        dbParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(dbParam);
        
        // Some other output parameters
        // ...
        
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlPipe sqlpipe = Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext.Pipe;
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecord record = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecord(mdDos);

        sqlpipe.SendResultsStart(record);

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            record.SetValue(0, reader[5]);

            sqlpipe.SendResultsRow(record);
        }
        sqlpipe.SendResultsEnd();
        reader.Close();
        db2connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I've already expanded the console test application to also connect with OdbcConnection and DB2Connection (by referencing the IBM.Data.DB2.dll used in the IBM driver).
I get both of them to connect as well, but once again, when using this in the CLR procedure, I get stuck.

When using Odbc, I get the following error:

```
SqlException (0x80131904): A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "clrGetData": 
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1, D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLIO.DLL).
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
```

When using the IBM dll, we're having troubles because we can't add external references without adding them to SQL Server as assemblies as well.
Since the IBM driver itself probably references a whole lot of other non-supported references, this would be a whole other problem to fix.

These are the connection strings we're using for each method:

```
// OleDb:
Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Database=<DB Name>;Hostname=<IP Address>;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=<Port Number>;Uid=<Username>;Pwd=<Password>;

// Odbc:
Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1};Database=<DB Name>;Hostname=<IP Address>;Port=<Port Number>;Protocol=TCPIP;UID=<Username>;PWD=<Password>;

// IBM DB2:
Server=<IP Address>:<Port Number>;Database=<DB Name>;UID=<Username>;PWD=<Password>;
```

I've tried googling a lot of those problems, but Google is not my friend in this, and no solution seems to work yet.

What method would be best to connect to a DB2 database inside a CLR procedure in SQL Server?
And what could be wrong with our setup/code?

**Edit:**

As asked by commenter below, the output of the `db2level` command:

```
D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11050" with level identifier
"0601010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.0.1077", "s1906101300",
"DYN1906101300WIN64", and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name
"DB2COPY1".
```

**Solution:**

The solution was in two parts:

1. There was a problem with the 11.5.0 IBM DB2 Client in regards to loading the DB2CLIO.dll file: (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT30451).
   Therefore the latest fix patch was installed on the database server.
2. The MSSQLSERVER user was added to the Windows group of DB2 users to resolve the permission issue.

Comment: need the connection string for the DB2 which isn't posted.  The connection string needs to be modified.

Comment: Added the connection strings.

Comment: At the time the connection to Db2 gets attempted, is directory `D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\` on the PATH ?   Also, can you confirm __which__ Db2 driver package you installed (is it clidriver, runtime-client etc), and can you confirm the plain-text output of the `db2level` command in 'D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\'

Comment: You are using an ODBC data source.  Click on the START button in windows and type "ODBC Data Source".  Check if IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER driver is installed.

Comment: Also make sure these instructions were followed : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=installing-requirements-db2-products and all the patches were installed : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=overview-fix-pack-summary&force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng The driver is indeed installed, in fact there's two: `IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER` and `IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1` listed. It's the latter we're using. Our partner (owning the DB2 database) did the installation, but they've done these before for other partners, so I'm assuming they did it correctly.

Comment: @mao The bin-location is indeed included in the PATH variable when the connection is attempted. I should check with our partner, but I know they installed the full IBM DB2 client (whatever that means) on the server. As for the output of the db2level command, I've added it to the original post.

Comment: The error says "ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1, D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLIO.DLL)." May be it is the permissions?  What happens if an admin run the app?

Comment: It is unwise to deploy "fixpack 0" of any IBM database product on production. You should get that replaced asap by the currently available fixpack (11.5.7.0).There may be more information in the client db2diag.log (if the fat Db2-client was installed = full client). You should verify that the db2-client correctly connects to the same database (with same credentials) when run by the same user-account that the CLR stored-proc tries to use (use the db2cli validate -connect -dsn X -user Y -pwd Z , where X,Y,Z are the dbname, user and password).

Comment: @jdweng The app was already run by an admin

Comment: @mao We indeed found a case on IBM where there was a problem in 11.5 with the loading of DB2CLIO.dll, so our partner has installed the latest fix patch of the client. The previous error seems to be resolved now, but there seems to be some permission problems as well, see my next comment.

Comment: @jdweng See previous comment: we're now getting: `ERROR [08004] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1092N  The requested command or operation failed because the user ID does not have the authority to perform the requested command or operation. User ID: "MSSQLSERVER".` We've already given the MSSQLSERVER user explicit read and execute rights on the IBM folder where the driver is located, but I'll check with our partner once again.

Comment: The SQL1092N is from Db2. The account MSSQLSERVER is maybe not in the correct groups (local groups, or ldap groups, or Active-Directory-groups), or else that account lacks required GRANT permissions in the database. Competent troubleshooting required. Seems odd to have a "partner" that does not do this basic stuff.

Comment: @mao : Could windows be blocking authentication by using username and password?  May require a Windows credential instead, or a windows setting need to be changed.

Comment: @jdweng   Run the `db2cli validate -connect ...` as mentioned above. Use `db2trc` to see what is happening under the hood. Key is competent troubleshooting. Don't you have a nearly-matching pre-production environment on which such stuff is rehearsed and automated?

Comment: Check the log files in SQL Server Management Studio to see what login was used.  The log file is in the SSMS explorer under Management.  SQL Server has two types of Credentials. 1) Windows 2) SQL Server.  You need to look at the connection string for SQL Server to see the type.  Post connection string.  SQL Database the MDF file can be either attached to a server or not attached.  When attached use Server=myServerAddress;. Attached use AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf.  Never both. Using window credentail us Integrated Security=true; SQL credentials username/password.  Never both.

Comment: @Jenzz What account does the MSSQLSERVER (or other instance name) service account log on as? That is the account that you need to test with. Also, if the `PATH` environment variable has the DB2 stuff added in the "User" variables, then that could be a problem, in which case you simply move that (i.e. the relevant `PATH` stuff) to the "System" variables. This log on account might also impact permissions to log into DB2, as per the new error message. You said that you tested on the server itself, but did you test using that same log on account?

Comment: @mao The MSSQLSERVER user indeed needed to be added to the correct Windows group to have the permissions. Thanks for the help, also to the other contributors. I've added the solutions to the original post, but if you add an answer I'll accept it as solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by:

- ensuring that the latest fixpack of the Db2 fat client was installed (previously a fixpack 0 was installed, which is usually unsuitable for production).
- ensuring that the userid being used to connect to Db2 (from MS-SQLServer) was a member of the correct loca/ldap/ActiveDirectory group that grants the required access to the Db2 database and its objects.

Always check with the latest fixpacks of IBM database products and drivers, these are downloadable from fixpack central website.